Files and std::array in C++
I have to use various files that have different amounts of numbers in them and calculate certain totals. The only problem I am having with my code is that when I am reading from the file and passing numbers into an array, the last number in the file is repeatedly accepted into the array when it should just end. Please help with solving this, I do not understand why it is not stopping once it reaches the end of the file.
My code is below:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

const int kMaxSize {30};

std::array < int, kMaxSize > ProcessFile(std::ifstream &infile, int &num_grades);
double CalculateFinalGrade(std::array < int, kMaxSize > grades, int &num_grades);
int CalculateTotal(std::array < int, kMaxSize > grades, int &num_grades);
char CalculateLetter(double final_grade);

int main(){

    std::string filename{};
    std::cout << "Enter the input file: ";
    std::cin >> filename;

    std::ifstream infile { filename };

    if (!infile){
            std::cout << '\n' << filename << " does not exist.\n";
            return 1;
        }

    int num_grades {};
    double final_grade {};
    char letter_grade {};
    int points_earned {};
    int max_points {};
    std::array < int, kMaxSize > grades {};

    max_points = num_grades * 100;
    grades = ProcessFile(infile, num_grades);

    // this is block checking contents to array
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (int i{0}; i < kMaxSize; i++){
            std::cout << grades.at(i) << " ";
        }
    std::cout << '\n';
    // end of block

    final_grade = CalculateFinalGrade(grades, num_grades);
    points_earned = CalculateTotal(grades, num_grades);
    letter_grade = CalculateLetter(final_grade);

    infile.close();

    std::cout << '\n' << "Number of Grades: " << std::setw(11) << std::right << num_grades;
    std::cout << '\n' << "Total Points Earned: " << std::setw(8) << std::right << points_earned;
    std::cout << '\n'  << "Max Possible Points: " << std::setw(8) << std::right << max_points << '\n';
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1);
    std::cout << '\n' << "Final Grade: " << std::setw(7) << std::right << letter_grade << std::setw(8) << std::right << final_grade << "%" << '\n';

    return 0;
}

std::array <int, kMaxSize >  ProcessFile(std::ifstream &infile, int &num_grades){
    int number {};
    std::array < int, kMaxSize > grades {};
    
    infile >> number;
    while (infile){
        for (int i{0}; i < kMaxSize; i++){
            grades.at(i) = number;
            num_grades = num_grades + 1;
            infile >> number;
        }
    }

    return grades;
}

double CalculateFinalGrade(std::array < int, kMaxSize > grades, int &num_grades){
    double final_grade{};
    int max_points {};
    max_points = num_grades * 100;
    double points_earned {};
    for (int i{0}; i < kMaxSize; i++){
            points_earned += grades.at(i);
        }
    if (max_points != 0){
        final_grade = points_earned / max_points * 100;
    } else {
        final_grade = 0;
    }
    return final_grade;
}

int CalculateTotal(std::array < int, kMaxSize > grades, int &num_grades){
    double points_earned {};
    for (int i{0}; i < num_grades; i++){
            points_earned += grades.at(i);
        }
    return points_earned;
}

char CalculateLetter(double final_grade){
    if (final_grade >= 90){
        return 'A';
    } else if (final_grade < 90 && final_grade >= 80){
        return 'B';
    } else if (final_grade < 80 && final_grade >= 70){
        return 'C';
    } else if (final_grade < 70 && final_grade >= 60){
        return 'D';
    } else {
        return 'F';
    }
}

I have also tried using a for loop, but I had the same problem.

while (infile) is the same issue like with while (!infile.eof()).

The main problem here is the incorrect use of loops, not the condition in the loop.

You should use std::vector, it is much more flexible and doesn't require you to know the exact file size up front. Also learn to pass array (or vector) by  reference, and if you use ProcessFile(std::istream&) you can also have a "test file" in code of type std::istringstream

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/62576

Look at your code (simplified)
infile >> number;
while (infile){
    for (int i{0}; i < kMaxSize; i++){
        ...
        infile >> number;
    }
}

For some reason you have used two loops when only one is needed. This code reads one number, checks the file, then reads kMaxSize numbers before it checks the file again, and if the file was OK at that point it would read another kMaxSize numbers, and so on.
This is why the last number gets repeatedly added to the array. Your for loop reads kMaxSize numbers without checking if there are any more to read. The check only happens in the while loop, but that check only happens after the for loop has ended. It's should be clear that the main problem is that you have written two loops, when you should only use one.
The other error you have is while (infile). This tests if the end of file has been reached, but that is not the correct test because it is possible to read the last number in a file without reaching the end of file, (this happens when there are spaces or newlines after the last number). Instead the best test is while (infile >> number), that tests if you can actually read a number, which is what you want.
Putting that together here is the correct code
int i = 0;
while (i < kMaxSize && infile >> number)
{
    grades.at(i) = number;
    num_grades = num_grades + 1;
    ++i;
}

Instead of using two loops I've used && to connect the two things you want to test for, the loop says 'while I still have more room in the array AND I can still read a number, add the number to the array'.

Possible simplification for(num_grades = 0; num_grades < grades.size() && infile >> grades[num_grades]; ++num_grades) {}

good point, essentially, the function becomes one line of code: for (num_grades=0;  num_grades<kMaxSize && infile>>grades[num_grades];  num_grades++ );

As others have already pointed out, your loop has too much extra.
Based on what you already have, I recommend to modify ProcessFile from this (your version):
std::array <int, kMaxSize >  ProcessFile(std::ifstream &infile, int &num_grades){
    int number {};
    std::array < int, kMaxSize > grades {};
    
    infile >> number;
    while (infile){
        for (int i{0}; i < kMaxSize; i++){
            grades.at(i) = number;
            num_grades = num_grades + 1;
            infile >> number;
        }
    }

    return grades;
}

to this below (see how much code was commented out):
std::array <int, kMaxSize >  ProcessFile(std::ifstream &infile, int &num_grades){
    int number {};
    std::array < int, kMaxSize > grades {};
    
    //infile >> number;
    //while (infile){
        for (int i{0}; infile>>number && i < kMaxSize; i++){
            grades.at(i) = number;
            num_grades = num_grades + 1;
            //infile >> number;
        }
    //}

    return grades;
}

That's a minimal modification to make it work.
Note: your condition while (infile) would repeatedly put the last number into the array until the array is completely filled up, because (infile) is never going to be passed as zero to while (infile) before the loop exits. (bold text is edited)

infile will become false when infile >> number reaches the end of file (or any other error). The problem is not so nuch the test itself, more about when it was being applied.

Also in your code I would reverse infile >> number && i < kMaxSize (i.e.  i < kMaxSize && infile >> number). There's no point trying to read a number when you have no room in the array.

@john, yes. when infile becomes zero, OP's for-loop doesn't pass it to while (infile) until the array is completely filled up. Also, when infile becomes zero, the number doesn't update, but stays at the last value. Anyway, I'll update my answer.
